# Get notified when a new custom field is added or an existing field metadata is updated

Tags: apex, sobject

I would like to get alerted when a custom field is added or if an existing field metadata is updated such as if it's data classification setting has changed.

Programmatically only thing I can think of is doing something like this to retrieve nightly and doing a compare from the previous night as stated here https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000g4aRQAQ:

```
List < Schema.SObjectType > gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values();      
Map<String , Schema.SObjectType > globalDescription = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();   
        
for ( Schema.SObjectType f : gd ) {  
  
    Schema.sObjectType objType = globalDescription.get(f.getDescribe().getName() );  
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r1 = objType.getDescribe();   
    Map<String , Schema.SObjectField > mapFieldList = r1.fields.getMap();    
  
    for ( Schema.SObjectField field : mapFieldList.values() ) {    
      
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = field.getDescribe();    
  
        if ( fieldResult.isAccessible() ) {    
          
            System.debug('Field Name is ' + objType + '.' + fieldResult.getName() );  
              
        }   
          
    }  
      
}
```

But this seems a lot of work. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only other method I could think of is use out of box Audit [logs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_monitorsetup.htm&type=5). This can be downloaded and compared to see what changed everyday.

Note Event Monitoring does not log events for Object creation yet if you are thinking around those lines.

If you want to do this in [Source Tracked Sandboxes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_setup_enable_source_tracking_sandboxes.htm) you can look into [Source Member](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sourcemember.htm) object (Note it is tooling object) and do an SOQL to see if component has changed or not or there is a new entry.

> In nutshell whatever you do you will need run a scheduled process on a daily basic or hourly to get this info.